# Asp.net 4.6 - ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I was given the task of fixing an old web api which was reported as broken in production. When I cloned down the repo and attempted to run it in VS, Chrome began giving the ERR_CONNECTION_RESET error. What is more, there is never any output despite a successful build. For example, I go into the Global.asax file and add a few Debug.WriteLine() and Trace.TraceInformation() statements straight up in the protected void Application_Start() method. There are no results. I am confused as to how this is even possible - what could be the cause of not being able to print anything to the output window?

Here is the WebApiApplication class, which is part of Global.asax. Understandably, this is limited information, but for the time being, I do not know how to narrow down the problem.

```
public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Log to console?");
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        var someList = new List<string> { (Add some items) };

        var v = new SomeClass(SomeArgument, someList);

        Application["v"] = v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Debug.WriteLine and Trace.Whatever only work if `DEBUG` and `TRACE` are defined in the build. Are you building from VS in debug mode?

Comment: Yes. DEBUG and TRACE are defined.

Comment: What happens if you set a breakpoint? Does it reach it?

Comment: @mason As a matter of fact, no. A breakpoint set on the first line of Application_Start() is never reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was IIS Express being set to a port it is not meant to be run on. This was fixed by going into the Web tab of Project properties, locating the Servers section and entering http://localhost:50490/ for IIS Express.